# php pass json to angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

this is my php code,

```
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $foodList[] = array();
  while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
      $foodList[] = $row;
  }
} else {}

echo json_encode($foodList);
```

this is my js code:

```
var $promise = $http.post('foodList.php');

$promise.then(function(msg){
  var foodList = msg.data;

  if (foodList) 
    {
      //$scope.foodList = foodList;
      alert(foodList);
    }
  else
    {
      //$scope.msg = "Error user name or password";
    }
```

this is output:

`$promise.then(function(msg){*msg = Object {data: Array[1], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}*
var foodList = msg.data;*foodList = [Array[0]]*`

So: actually 3 data in my data base, but in output just only Array[1]?
How to fix it ?
THX

Comment: change `$foodList[] = array();` to $foodList = array();

Comment: the output is become to array[0]

Comment: var_dump($foodList) in your php file and make sure your php file show 3 data

Comment: if i set php echo the $count, i will get 3 for return, y this happened?

Comment: you count the `$query` but in while loop use `$result` why?

Answer (score 0):

Your php syntax and the usage of commands are wrong in some places. Here is the corrected code. Please compare and see the difference.

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count > 0) {

  // output data of each row
  $foodList = array();

  while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {        
      array_push($foodList, $row);
  }
}

echo json_encode($foodList);
```

This should work if you are selecting the rows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your count the $query variable so in your while loop use $query variable

```
<?php
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $foodList = array();
  while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
      $foodList[] = $row;
  }
}

echo json_encode($foodList);
```

?>